# "On" state of a UISwitch

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiswitch

I have a switch and I want to have something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if name.text == "Jack"{
        switch.on = false
    }
}
```

But it's not working! How can I change the state of a switch when the view controller is loading?

Answer (score 3):

`UISwitch` has a property `isOn` to turn the switch on and off.
Also don't use the name `switch` since this is a reserved keyword in Swift.

Comment: I named it Switch but just for my question I said switch. When I tried `switch.isOn = false`  I get an error  `Value of type 'PWSwitch' has no member 'isOn'`

Answer (score 0):

To disable switch :

```
switch.isEnabled = false
```

To change the switch state to `off`:

```
switch.isOn = false
```

Comment: I get an error  `Value of type 'PWSwitch' has no member 'isOn'`

Answer (score 0):

To disable switch :

**Objective C**

```
[switch setEnabled:NO];
```

**Swift**

```
switch.isEnabled = false
```

Comment: I get an error  `Value of type 'PWSwitch' has no member 'isOn'`

Comment: @leo0019 What you have make with switch? Is it IBOutlet or IBAction? Your mistake should be to create IBActions where the instructions said to create IBOutlets.