# How to get boolean value from switch state?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiswitch

I want to get the current Boolean of the switch. how to do that in swift4 ?

```
@IBOutlet weak var switch_1: UISwitch!
var switch1_state: Bool = swich_1.get ???
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [State of UISwitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46899032/state-of-uiswitch)

Comment: Please take a moment to review the documentation for `UISwitch`. This is really trivial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply call `switch.isOn` to get the state of the `UISwitch`, but you should rather create an IBAction for your `UISwitch`, which will be called every time the state of the Switch changes.

You can store the switch state in a computed property if you don't need to be notified every time the state of the switch changes or store the value in a stored property, whose value you can change from the connected IBAction.

```
var switchState:Bool {
    return switch.isOn
}
```

You should also conform to the Swift naming convention, which is lowerCamelCase for function and variable names.

Answer (score 0):

First of all please use *camelCased* rather than *snake_cased* variable names.

Second of all there's a typo – missing `t` – in the second line.

And finally please use code completion (there is only one `Bool`property) or read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswitch):

[image]